# click function call with $(this) from another function in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click function which is given below

```
$('.page-nav li').click(function(event){

    console.log("clickedTab-page-nav-first-before set ="+Session.get('clickedTab'));

    Session.set('clickedTab',event.target.id);
      //var sel = event.prevUntil("[class*=active]").andSelf();
    var sel = $(this).prevUntil("[class*=active]").andSelf(); //find all previous li 
                                                              //of li which have
                                                              //class=active
    sel = sel.add(sel.eq(0).prev()); // include the  that li also(Now all li elements).                      
    sel.removeClass('active'); //Remove the active.
      //sel = event.nextUntil("[class*=active]").andSelf(); //Also for top to bottom 
                                                            //(Viceversa)
    sel = $(this).nextUntil("[class*=active]").andSelf();
    sel = sel.add(sel.eq(-1).next());
    sel.removeClass('active');
      //event.addClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active'); //Now add class active for the clicked li
    var rightcontent="";

    console.log("clickedTab-page-nav-second-after set = "+Session.get('clickedTab'));

    switch($(this).attr('id')){
            case  'rfq':
               .......
               .....
        }
});
```

Then next is I want to call this click function from another place

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     console.log("clickedTab-page load = "+Session.get('clickedTab'));
     if(Session.get('clickedTab')!=null||Session.get('clickedTab')!= undefined){
         alert("Got It");
         //$('.page-nav li').click(event);
         $('.page-nav li').click(); //this is not working
     }
});
```

Now the problem is page click function in  if condition is not working. However I got the alert. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you put `$('.page-nav li').click(function(event){` inside `document.ready`?

Comment: also make sure that the event registration happens before the `click` event is triggered

Comment: If you don't put `$('.page-nav li').click(function(event){` inside `document.ready` or you're dealing with dynamically created elements. You need delegated event `$(document).on("click",".page-nav li",function(event){`

Comment: @KhanhTO yes i put $('.page-nav li').click(function(event){ inside the document redy and also its not dynamically created elemts

Comment: @ArunPJohny how the event registration can be done

Comment: Remember to call `$('.page-nav li').click(function(event){` before `$('.page-nav li').click();`

Comment: kk  now that $('.page-nav li').click(); is working . but there is  some problems with $(this). that  takes the first option ,then next option .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not really using the `event` parameter in your function and you state you wish to call it outside of an event chain so you could change it to be a regular function

```
var setupClicktab = function(id){

    console.log("clickedTab-page-nav-first-before set ="+Session.get('clickedTab'));

    Session.set('clickedTab',id);
    ...
}
```

the you'd use it like:

```
$('.page-nav li').click(function(event){return setupClicktab(event.target.id);});
```

and in document ready

```
setupClicktab.Call($('.page-nav li'),Session.get('clickedTab'));
```

The latter call class it in the context of the selection (that is this inside the function will refer to the selection(1). It also passes the value stored in the session variable in as the id.

a side note. Your test

```
 if(Session.get('clickedTab')!=null||Session.get('clickedTab')!= undefined)
```

could simply be

```
if(Session.get('clickedTab'))
```

Unless you might store either an empty string, zero or the boolean value false in that variable. But seeing how it's used that's unlikely since they are all invalid values for the id attribute

(1)This is slightly different than in the click event where it refers to the DOM element)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its works .Great. Actually we don't need that 'this' variable.

Comment: @manuthalasseril I could see the need either it's was mainly for completeness. To get close to the original and to make it less error prone if you update the function later so that it then does actually use this

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `$('.page-nav li').click(function(event){` inside `document.ready` and ***before*** your `$('.page-nav li').click();`. Because if you call `.click` when the DOM is not ready, there are chances that ***there is no event handler attached***

If you don't put `$('.page-nav li').click(function(event){` inside `document.ready` OR you're dealing with dynamically created elements. You need delegated event `$(document).on("click",".page-nav li",function(event){`

From [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)